# What's wrong with this net use command?

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2003, net-use

I am entering the following command on Windows Server 2003

```
net use X: \\Samba_Server\gis  /user:Administrator <admin-pwd>  /persistent:yes
```

And I get the following error:

```
System error 1326 has occurred.
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Without the `/user:Administrator <admin-pwd>`, it mounts fine. I want the credentials to be persistent across logins.

Comment: What if you put the <admin-pwd> in quotes like "<admin-pwd>"? Sometimes it helps if there are special characters in the PW. What if you leave the password away altogether? Are you prompted to enter the PW?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might have to specify explicitly that you want to reference the user account on the remote system, otherwise, Windows might try to establish the connection referencing your local Administrator account.

To do this, supply the domain (in this case the name of the remote computer) with the `/user:` parameter:

```
net use X: \\Samba_Server\gis /user:Samba_Server\Administrator <admin-pwd> /persistent:yes
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax command that you have entered is correct. Error 1326 is a common error number used to denote authentication failures on Windows system. These failures are usually related, but not limited to:

1. account does not exist
2. guest account needs to be enabled
3. auto-logon and blank password is enabled on remote computer
4. folder or drive permissions shared on the remote computer

In your case, if you have checked that the account you are using exists on the remote computer(1), the problem might be caused by point 3. SAMBA shares has a configuration option when turned on would exhibit this behavior on Windows clients.

```
guest only = yes
```

More information on this option can be found
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTONLY

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause for this is invalid date/time on one of machines.

Comment: Can you explain how that misconfiguration could cause the problem (symptoms) described n the question?

Comment: I can't find the article(s) - but there are several known issues with Windows and time sync.  There are settings that control how far off Windows will allow two computers to drift and still talk to each other - I believe to prevent replay attacks.  The "known" a priora is to make sure the time is in sync between computers (within minutes).  For those of us who have been-there-done-that, don't underestimate this basic check.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thank you Dmitry. The time on the computer I tried to connect to was shifted by 40 minutes.